# Vbscript - Issues in getting the Excel column Index

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am stuck on an issue while creating a simple function that returns the excel column index, given the column name. I am not able to understand why is the script is behaving so weirdly(please see code comments for issues). I know there must be a silly mistake but I am just not able to find it. Will greatly appreciate your help!

The following is the function which was supposed to return the index of the column in an excel sheet:

```
function fn_findColumnIndex(sheetObj, strColumnName)
    Dim i, j, strTemp, intIndex
    j = sheetObj.usedRange.Columns.Count        'will replace it later with better ways to get column count. This works fine for now when I tried to print the value
    intIndex = 0
    for i = 1 to j step 1
        strTemp = sheetObj.cells(1,j).value     'Targeting the values in the 1st row(i.e, the column names)
        'msgbox strTemp                         'when I uncomment this line, all the values in row 1 are displayed as blank. That's the reason the function always return 0. But why are these values blank?
        if strComp(strTemp,strColumnName,1) = 0 then
            intIndex = j
            Exit For
        end if
    next
    fn_findColumnIndex = intIndex
end function
```

The following is the piece of code which is calling the above-mentioned function:

```
set objExcel = createObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = false
objExcel.displayAlerts = false
strCDPath = "E:\Base\TestDesign\CycleDriver\CycleDriver.xlsx"
Set objBook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open(strCDPath)
set objSheet = objBook.WorkSheets("CycleDriver")
intRunColumn = fn_findColumnIndex(objSheet,"Run")               'getting the value 0 here. Why?
intModuleColumn = fn_findColumnIndex(objSheet,"Module")         'getting the value 0 here. Why?
intTestScriptColumn = fn_findColumnIndex(objSheet,"TestScript") 'getting the value 0 here. Why?
objBook.close
objExcel.quit
```

This is how the Sheet looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if vbscript supports something like vba's IsError but if the existence of the column header labels is guaranteed, I would try something like this.

```
intRunColumn = objExcel.match("Run", objSheet.rows(1), 0)
intModuleColumn = objExcel.match("Module", objSheet.rows(1), 0)
intTestScriptColumn = objExcel.match("TestScript", objSheet.rows(1), 0)
```

Your own function was failing due to using i as the counter in,

```
for i = 1 to j step 1
```

... but using j to gather data like,

```
strTemp = sheetObj.cells(1, j).value
'should be,
strTemp = sheetObj.cells(1, i).value
'also
intIndex = i
```

So you were always getting the header label at UsedRange's right end.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an alternative. This code snippet is working fine and is way more elegant solution than mine. I will be using this in my code. But, still not sure what's wrong with the function I posted. Just curious.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It really was a silly mistake. Thanks again :)

Comment: No worries; we've all had 'programmer's moments'.