# Checking number of Occurrences In Workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

I am trying to iterate through many worksheets in a workbook and see if foo and bar are present then add to this specific cell. For some reason my code iterates through the worksheets, but does not add to the cell.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws As Worksheets 
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ind = 9
    For I = 1 To ws_num
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
        Do While ind <= 39
            If Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "bar" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "foo" Then
                Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value + 1
                Exit For
            End If
            ind = ind + 1
        Loop

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ind = 9` be inside your `For` loop? The way it is now, `ind` will just grow and grow until it's done, not start at row 9 for each sheet.

Comment: Cell `C7` on `scrap` increments for me. But only if I put "bar" and "foo" in one of the cells in range.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rOutput As Range
    Dim lCount As Long

    Set rOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scrap").Range("C7")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lCount = lCount + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("A9:A39"), "bar", ws.Range("G9:G39"), "foo")
    Next ws

    rOutput.Value = rOutput.Value + lCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()

Dim ws As Worksheets 
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To ws_num
    ind = 9
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
    Do While ind <= 39
        If Worksheets(I).Range("A" & ind).Value = "bar" And Worksheets(I).Range("G" & ind).Value = "foo" Then
            Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("scrap").Range("C7").Value + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        ind = ind + 1
    Loop

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why Activate ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I) if you keep repeating the parent worksheet reference? Maybe add a `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I) ... End With` block.

Comment: @Jeeped I agree that would be better. I just took OP's code and fixed the places i thought was creating the problem in order to stay as true to his code as possible. If I had to write the code from the bottom i would do it similar to tigeravatar. This raises a good question actually: What is best practice here on SO - providing the "best" answer, or providing a fix to OP's code? To make it applicable to as many people as possible, maybe it's the former. What do you think? :)

Comment: Personally, I take it case-by-case. I often throw out the OP's code completely but try to add some explanation of where they went wrong (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794289/vbscript-issues-in-getting-the-excel-column-index/50794513#50794513)). Other times I might judge them at a level where the 'best method' is completely beyond their comprehension and helping them improve their own code is the better path to take. I know that latter one sounds condescending but sometimes you have to learn to walk before you can fly.

Comment: @Jeeped Wise words :)